# How could creatures evole without night vision in a dayless world?

Tags: evolution, vision

Basically, I want creatures that are as human-like as possible to have evolved on a dayless planet. Nevermind how there could even be lfe, I aready have that covered. I want them to have as close to normal human night-vision as possible, no echolocation, etc. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Please clarify what does dayless imply: cave like, with no light source at all, or a normal night sky with stars and maybe moons in the sky?

Comment: No light, no sight. IR maybe.

Comment: I think on a dayless world, even if it was the type of dayless where you always had a full moon, you would go extinct if your primary sense was human night vision since a lot of other animals easily see much better.